# How can I convert [[String]] converted to String value back to the original type [[String]]?

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a small project in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) that is something like simple excel. Basically my spreadsheet is represented as the list of list (type is **[[String]]**). The example board looks like:

```
[["2", "=SUM(A0:C0)", "1"], ["7", "2", "3"], ["2", "=SUM(A0:B0)", ""]]
```

One of the requirements is to save the board in file and also possibility to import it from file.

To save in file I'm converting the board to String (to be able to write it in the file) :

```
filenameOut <- getLine
writeFile filenameOut (show (board))
putStrLn "Board saved to file."
```

To upload the board:

```
filenameIn <- getLine
handle <- openFile filenameIn ReadMode
input <- hGetContents handle
```

But input is a String "[["2", "=SUM(A0:C0)", "1"], ["7", "2", "3"], ["2", "=SUM(A0:B0)", ""]]" and I want to convert it back to the [[String]]. I tried to used regex but it seems to be not a good solution.

Is there some other solutions to do some kind of inverse operation to have back [[String]]?

Comment: I'm very confused by the String `"[["2", "=SUM(A0:C0)", "1"], ["7", "2", "3"], ["2", "=SUM(A0:B0)", ""]]"`. It seems to be invalid.

Comment: @eli-sadoff, Yes, I just want to indicate that this is a String. In the file it looks like: [["2", "=SUM(A0:C0)", "1"], ["7", "2", "3"], ["2", "=SUM(A0:B0)", ""]]. When I upload it from file the way I presented in question it is of String type.

Comment: The terms you are looking for is `read`ing or "parsing" the string.  The process of looking at text to obtain a structured value is generally referred to as parsing.  We could get more technical and discuss lexing, but if you look for CSV parsers or just the `read` function then you'll do alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`Read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Read) typeclass in the prelude.

`read :: (Read a) => String -> a` is a partial function that tries to a parse a value of type `a` from the input string. Not all types have a `Read` instance, but for those that do, for any `val :: A`, then `read (show val) :: A` will give you back `val`; in other words, `read` is `show`'s inverse.

Using `read` is a bit tricky since generally speaking, the compiler will have no way of knowing what output type you want. If you hear GHC groaning about an 'ambiguous type' you should annotate the result of `read`, like this:

```
read "[[\"1\", \"hello\"], []" :: [[String]]
```